# How do I use MS Word VBA code to shade cells with specific text after seaching a a specific column?

Tags: vba, ms-word, tablecolumn

I am working on a table in word and have the following code to find and shade the cells with the words "Yes" and "No".  What code do I use to do this specifically in columns 3 & 4?

```
Dim r As Range

Sub UBC()
    color "No", wdRed
    color "Yes", wdGreen
End Sub

    Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
        Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
           With r.Find
           Do While .Execute(FindText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
        r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
           Loop
        End With
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Range.Information` property to determine if the match is in a table. Then you would use the cell's `ColumnIndex` property to determine if it is in the required column.

```
Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = ActiveDocument.Content
   With r.Find
      Do While .Execute(FindText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
         If r.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            With r.Cells(1)
               If .ColumnIndex = 3 Or .ColumnIndex = 4 Then .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
            End With
         End If
      Loop
   End With
End Function
```

Comment: @JDavis - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)